# JerseyServlet doesn't save object in memory

Tags: json, rest, jakarta-ee

since I was sitting the whole day and could not figure out the problem, I am hoping you can help me.

Here you can see a Jersey service class. This class should simply store teams, and you can add and retrieve teams.

```
@Path("/jsonServices")
public class JerseyRestService {

    Tournament tournament = new Tournament();

    @POST
    @Path("/send")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response consumeJSON(Team team) {
        tournament.addTeam(team);
        return Response.status(200).entity(team.toString() + tournament.teams.size()).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/print/{name}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Team produceJSON(@PathParam("name") String name) {
        return tournament.getTeam(name);
    }
}


public class Tournament {
    List<Team> teams = new ArrayList<Team>();

    public boolean addTeam(Team student) {
        return teams.add(student);
    }

    public Team getTeam(String name) {
        System.err.println("Halleluja");
        return teams.get(0);
    }
}
```

I am adding teams with a simple client:

```
public class JerseyPost {
    private static Client client;
    private static WebResource webResource;
    private static ClientResponse response;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();          
            clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, true);
            client = Client.create(clientConfig);
            webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/JerseyJSONExample/rest/jsonServices/send");
            webResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

            response = webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class, new Team("1", "Batman1","Robin1"));

            if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed: HTTP error code: " + response.getStatus());
            }

            System.out.println(response.getEntity(String.class));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunetly the teams are not saved. After I add a team the list size is always just one.

When I try a GET request the list is always empty.

Thank you very much, for any help you can prvide me.

Regards Robert

Comment: I suspect, but am not sure, that each call is producing a new Tournament() instance.  The Service classes aren't supposed to have state like that.  You need to put your Tournament off in some singleton data store thing or something.  To test if my original assertion is correct, make Tournament static and see if that starts getting it persisted in memory.  Then figure out how to get it out of the Service class and into its own datastore thing.

Comment: Thank you very much! You were absolutely right and it is working now.

I don't want store the data there, it is just for the mean time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html) Jersey creates new instance of Resource class  for every new request.

> Resource class  (JerseyRestService in your case)
>
> By default the life-cycle of root resource classes is per-request
>   which, namely that a new instance of a root resource class is created
>   every time the request URI path matches the root resource. This makes
>   for a very natural programming model where constructors and fields can
>   be utilized (as in the previous section showing the constructor of the
>   SparklinesResource class) without concern for multiple concurrent
>   requests to the same resource.
>
> So tournament.addTeam(team); you populate here will be available only for consumeJSON method

to solve your problem make 'tournament' as static so that it will be shared across all the instance

> static Tournament tournament = new Tournament();

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you very much! You were absolutely right and it is working now.